# Longest Common Substring without Dynamic programming or Suffix Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, longest-substring

Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual Question 8-3 part b asks to give a "simpler" BigO(nm) algorithm for finding the longest common substring that does not rely on dynamic programming. The obvious answer seems to be to use a suffix tree, however, Skiena uses the word "Simpler" I am not sure suffix trees are simpler than DP, maybe the search is simpler, but building a suffix tree in nm time complexity is anything but simple. So, I'm wondering, is there another way to solve this problem in O(nm) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's says we fixed starting position `i` in first(shorter) string `s`. Now Let's find its longest possible prefix in the longer string. It may be done in `O(n + m)` by examining [prefix function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)(or [z function](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107)) of string `s[i:] + # + t` where # is special symbol that doesn't exist in any of `s` and `t`.

Overall complexity is `O(n(n + m))` which is `O(nm)` if n < m